# How to force TypeScript to allow null as an index type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object inside a large project that uses null as a key and that cannot be changed, since it would break things all over the app.

However, I'm getting `Type null cannot be used as an index type. ts(2538)` all over the place. Is there a way to tell TypeScript to accept null as an object key the same way it accepts numbers as keys?

[demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsgTwPICMBWBTYsC8MDeAsAFAxkxgCuANtQFwwAMANCeTAIYMCMrp5KBgCY+AXxIlQkWAGsMCBtABOASzABzGAB8KNajDxVaAbgnEpEENQwA6aiHUAKRKkzYA2nIQBdAJTGgA)

Comment: Use `console.log(MyObject["null"]);`. Object keys are always strings (or symbols).

Comment: @AlexR You mean changing `[myKey]` to `[myKey ?? "null"]`? If there is no other way, that could solve my problem. It would be great if there was a way to just have TS accept nulls, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All keys in javascript are converted to strings or symbols. Even if assigned non string values, the keys are converted to string.

So `MyObject[null]` should become something like `MyObject['null']` and should work as is. All you have to do is use **'null'** (as a string) instead of `null` when accessing the property.

Note that there is another change required. The below statement means that `key` can be assgined any `string` value or the value `null`.

```
const key: string | null = null;
```

But `MyObject` only has three valid keys `a,b,null`. So you should modify your statement like:

```
const key: keyof typeof MyObject  = 'null';
```

or

```
const key  = 'null';
```

So, `key` can only be assigned valid `MyObject` keys.

```
const MyObject = {
    null: 0,
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
}

//const key: keyof typeof MyObject  = 'null';
const key = 'null';

console.log(MyObject[key]);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsgTwPICMBWBTYsC8MDeAsAFAxkxgCuANtQFwwAMANCeTAIYMCMrp5KBgCY+AXxIlQkWAGsMCBnIQgAZjCgIADhlXxk6LLBh4A5FVomA3BOJSIIahgB01EAHMAFIlSZsAbSUAXQBKSyA)

Answer (score 1):

In TypeScript, when using an object as an index type, the type system enforces that the index must be assignable to `string` or `number`. That's why you're getting the error `Type null cannot be used as an index type`.

Unfortunately, there is no way to directly tell TypeScript to accept `null` as a valid index type without modifying the TypeScript compiler or changing the definition of the object.

However, if modifying the object is not an option, you can work around this issue by using a type assertion (`as`) to override the type checking temporarily. Here's an example:

```js
const MyObject = {
    null: 0,
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
};

const key: string | null = null;

console.log(MyObject[key as keyof typeof MyObject]); // Use type assertion to bypass type checking
```

By using `key as keyof typeof MyObject`, you're essentially telling TypeScript to treat `key` as a valid key of the `MyObject` object. However, keep in mind that this bypasses type checking, so you need to ensure that `key` is a valid key at runtime; otherwise, you may encounter a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

So, in TypeScript they actively decided to [only allow the string or number type as index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types). Probably because most of the time, anyone trying to index into an object using something like null is indicative of an error.

In your case, you can do something like this:

```
function buildInverseMap(source: Array<string | null>) : {[key: string] : number} {
    var inverseMap: { [key: string]: number } = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        inverseMap[String(source[i])] = i; // coerce to string yourself
    }
    return inverseMap;
}     // example for function.

inverseMap[source[i] || "null"] = i;  // example for an object.
```

Hope that helps! Good luck.